# In web view after adding file in assests folder file is not loading

Tags: android, development-environment

I am creating an book app in which in child  activiy(DEscription activity) file will load as html extension from assests folder,file is added and its showing app is running smoothly,but content is not showing  when I am clicking on list its blank, nothing is coming there.

```
package com.example.javabook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class DescriptionActiviity extends AppCompatActivity {

private  static  final  String TAG ="DescriptionActivity";
private Context mContext;
private Bundle extras;
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_description_activiity);

    mContext = DescriptionActiviity.this;

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.simpleWebView);

    extras =getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras.equals(null)) {

        String data = extras.getString( "titles");

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: the coming is" +data);

        String  url = "file:///android_assest/"+data+".html";
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        WebSettings webSettings =webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    }

}
}
```

Comment: Pls answer  anyone

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are doing everything right, check your logcat and see if you are having any errors related to UriFileExposure. If you are, then you may run this code in your onCreate even though it isn't a decent solution.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        try {
            Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
            m.invoke(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your layout file and your html file for me to try on my end and see if I can replicate your problem